# Email Sending issue 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I have getting Swift_RfcComplianceException error while sending the mail

My code is like

```
Mail::send([],[],  function ($message) use ($fromName,$fromEmail,$subject,$data,$toEmilId){
                                                       $message->to($toEmilId)
                                                       ->from($fromEmail,$fromName)
                                                       ->subject($subject)
                                                       ->setBody($data,'text/html');
                                                                      
                                                   });
```

And getting error is

```
 "message": "Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.",
    "exception": "Swift_RfcComplianceException",
    "file": "E:\\NaveenNayak\\wamp-projects\\subscriptionapi\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Mime\\Headers\\MailboxHeader.php",
    "line": 355,
```

I have cleared
`php artisan cache:clear`,`php artisan config:clear`, and `php artisan config:cache` commands still getting the same error.

Please help me to solve this error

Comment: check $fromEmail ,$toEmilId ,$fromName,$data are empty. I believe its the issue because of empty values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like passed variable `$fromEmail` ,`$toEmilId` ,`$fromName`, are empty.

Also make sure to trim `$fromEmail` ,`$toEmilId` .Even if your email contain space begining or at the end also you get error.

For example i have given space in `$fromEmail` then i get following error

```
$fromEmail=" ****@gmail.com";
```

> Swift_RfcComplianceException Address in mailbox given [
> ****@gmail.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

if your from email or to email empty then you get following error

> Swift_RfcComplianceException Address in mailbox given [] does not
> comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

also if you email address invalid then you get following error

```
$toaddress="johnlobo" so this invalid email address then error
```

> Swift_RfcComplianceException Address in mailbox given [johnlobo]
> does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.